# How can simultaneous equatons be viewed?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was thinking about determinants and started to list ways that simultaneous equations making sense to me.  Here are the ones I have (feel free to correct if these are wrong): 
$$\begin{align} 
2x+3y=7 \\
 x+4y=6 \\
\end{align}$$
Here the solution is the ordered pair $(x,y)$Another way is to see the coefficients as a transformation matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2&3\\
1&4
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
7\\
6
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Here the solution is the column vector $[x,y]^T$
 that maps to the column vector $[7,6]^T$
 Another way is a linear combination of  column vectors:
$$x
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
1
\end{bmatrix} +y
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
4
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
7\\
6
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Here the solution are the scalars $x$ and $y$. Finally, and the one I'm least confident with, as a dot product or scalar projection. $$
\begin{align}
<2,3>\bullet<x,y>=7\\
<1,4>\bullet<x,y>=6
\end{align}$$ 
Here the solution is the vector $<x,y>$ with the given dot products. Here is my question; are these interpretations correct and are there any others? Thanks for any help.

Comment: They are correct, why do you want to write the same thing in more ways?

Comment: I started off trying to understand why a zero determinant implied  linear dependence. I couldn't get my head round that for ages. If a matrix was singular then there were no solutions (scalars $x$ and $y$) for a linear combination of the vectors to equal zero which confused me. I then looked at the other cases.I hope that makes sense,the rest is just curiosity.